# Looking for a very solid way to lock a metal frame into place

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I’m basically looking for a bomb proof way to lock a ≈80lb/40kg metal frame into place, with an electronic release.

Alternatively, looking for alternate ideas for the entire project below.

---

I’m building a solar panel rig to put in the roof of a van that can rotate to angle in any direction (360° rotational and +-60° tilt anyway)

My idea is fairly simple: build a metal frame, make it titleable with some linear actuators, and then stick this onto a lazy susan (a mechanical turn table)

The only snag I’m running into is how to lock the whole thing into place when it’s not moving.  I’m sure this is a solved problem and I’m just not aware of the solution.  I ideally want the lock to be electronically releasable, and allow 180° (Well 179°) rotation in either direction, though 359° in one direction would also work.  And it needs to be stable in 100mph/160kph winds while driving.

Any thoughts?  Thanks!!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139940/discussion-on-question-by-user39603-looking-for-a-very-solid-way-to-lock-a-metal).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question has been vandalized by the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ring of holes in the base with vertical pin(s) being driven by a solenoid to lock it in place at different angles of yaw.

If the base is rectangle with ends far from the lazy susan, to prevent wind from blowing it up in driving position you can have the ends slide it hold down brackets mounted on the roof of the car at each end.

A few ways to do this. Some are:

1. Mount brackets like an upside down 'L' on the car roof which the baseplate slides under. Will require the plate to have circular ends for proper clearance so it can rotate.
2. Have brackets both on the roof and under the plate that slide into each other. Does not require a rounding the ends of the plate. Optimally, those L-brackets would be curved throats and ends when looking at them from above. That would allow a tight horizontal fit. Otherwise the throat will need lateral clearance so they can rotate through each other. I suppose the much easier compromise would be to round just the ends of both brackets and not curve the throat.
3. Fancy ass arched/curved dovetail

In all cases, you want to slope the entryway to those brackets in the direction tangential to the rotational circle to guide things if there is vertical play. Otherwise it may crash. Will also probably want to treat those brackets as bearing surfaces.